# Mark method as deprecated without changing its source code

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I want to restrict the usage of some library methods in my project (so I get a warning when I use these methods). Is there a list of custom deprecated methods in IDEA?

Example: I should never use `PrimitiveIterator.OfInt.next()`. I should use `nextInt()` instead. I want to see a warning every time I use `next()`.

Comment: I think you can't without add the `@Deprecated` annotation in your code. If you search uses only in you current project, you can use the "Find usages" Intellij's features maybe ?

Comment: Which build tool are you using? For example, with Maven something of the kind might be possible with Maven Enforcer Plugin. Another solution might also be to customize checkstyle for that.

Comment: you can create a rule in checkstyle to apply that http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/ or in intellij with the cursor over the method name `ctrl+shift+a` search `add method` and an `add method to black list` option should appear

Comment: @Paizo It's a totally different thing. It's about parameter hints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the text cursor on a method or a call to a method you want to deprecate and type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, invoke `Annotate method '<name>'` and choose `java.lang.Deprecated`. If the method you are annotating is located in a library, IntelliJ IDEA will automatically store the annotation "externally" (i.e. in an xml file, the location of which you will be asked for).

[image: Annotate method intention in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1]

Another option is to create a pattern for the `Structural Search Inspection` to highlight any call to an undesirable method with a warning.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly I was looking for.

Comment: I don't see this option, has this feature been removed?

Comment: @StefanPaulNoack in recent IDEA versions this option is available on method declaration only, so you should go to declaration (Ctrl+B) first. This was done to avoid accidental annotations (see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-211649 for details).

Comment: @TagirValeev I see, but the option is not available for methods from the Kotlin standard library. I'd like to deprecate `removeAll` because it breaks horribly when called on a concurrent collection, and `removeIf` has since been added to Java.

Comment: It works, but if I checkout the project on another PC (using git for example) it does not work there... or after an Intellij update it doesn't work anymore.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3